# How Do I Extract String of Characters Between (Not Including) Two Matching Patterns Using Sed in conjunction with Multiplier?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract the character string between (but not including) two matching patterns using `sed`. My question is within the context of using regex multipliers in conjunction with the sed command

As an example,

- I am trying to extract the string: `PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD`  from
  `1139    "PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD 11/11 P`
- I was successful without using multipliers but not succesful using multipliers.

If it is possible, I would like to understand why the code using the multipliers is not working.

FYI, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS running on Microsoft WSL2

As a test, I tried the following, which was successful:

```
# Code:
echo '1139    "PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD 11/11 P' | sed 's/^.*\"\(.* \) *[0-9][0-9]\/.*/
\1/'
# Output:
PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD
```

However, I can not successfully produce the same result using multipliers. Instead of the above code, I tried:

```
# Attempted Code:
echo '1139    "PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD 11/11 P' | sed 's/^.*\"\(.* \) *[0-9]{2}\/.*/
\1/'
# Output:
1139    "PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD 11/11 P
```

I am trying to understand why the use of a "multiplier" to indicate a digit `[0-9]` should appear twice prior to the forward slash is not working -- i.e., `[0-9]{2}` portion of the `sed` command above.

Comment: To me it is difficult to understand what you want to achieve and why the two digits are important. I suggest to [edit] the question and add a few examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

After some more thought, I discovered I need to escape the curly braces `{` and `}` so that the `sed` command look like this:

```
# Command:
echo '1139    "PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD 11/11 P' | sed 's/^.*\"\(.* \) *[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}.*/\1/'

# Output:
PAYPAL *SPRINGER TXTBK ORD
```

Notice the placement of the backslashes, `\` in the `[0-9]\{2\}` portion of the `sed` command.

Comment: Well done! Keep posting (but with correct formatting of your code and data. Use the `{}` tool on the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to have correct formatting like `code/data/output/errMsgs`.) You can accept your own answer after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points. Good luck.